# Визуализация графа

Tags: javascript, python, c#, c++, графика

У меня есть матрица смежности и мне необходимо нарисовать по ней граф (Как на примере)

Поиск в гугле особых результатов не приносит.
Может у кого-то есть готовый код (на любом ЯП), пример  или хотя бы объяснение как это можно реализовать?
[image: Пример графа]

Comment: Дубль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408072/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1

Answer (score 1):

Копать в сторону [Graphvis](https://graphviz.org/).

Переводите свою матрицу в понятный ему формат:

```
graph {
    A -- B [label=1]
    B -- C [label=3]
}
```

Программой Graphvis превращаете в картинку:

[image: pic]

Comment: Он уже 4ый раз один вопрос генерит)